# Delete a control with specific name

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I wanna delete a button that I've added programmatically (and it has a key).
I'm using Controls.Remove(x) but I need to remove a control by key (instead of using its refernce).

How do I remove a control from `ControlCollection` using its key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

(**Recommended**) Use `RemoveByKey()`:

```
Controls.RemoveByKey(xName)
```

Find it with `Find()` (let me use verbose syntax to explain what it is) and then remove it with `Remove()` (to use if multiple controls with same name exist and you want to remove only first occurrence):

```
Controls.Remove(Controls.Find(xName, False).First())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming control name is "t1":

```
<container>.Controls.Remove(<container>.Controls("t1"))
```